# Append row from list stored in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have DataFrame with list in one column and would like to append each list member as a new line. Here an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['fruit','vegetable'], 'b': [['orange', 'banana'], ['apple']]})
df

    a          b
0   fruit      [orange, banana]
1   vegetable  [carrot]
```

and the result should be:

```
    a          b
0   fruit      [orange]
1   vegetable  [carrot]
2   fruit      [banana]
```

I know how to do it with loop (itertuples or iterrows) but I wonder if there's some more pythonic way than this:

```
for r in df[df['b'].str.len()>1].itertuples():
    for item in r.b:
        df = df.append({'a': r.a, 'b': [item]}, ignore_index=True)
df = df[df['b'].str.len()<2]
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752361/9081267) solution is nice as well

Comment: `df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.b.str.len())].assign(b=np.hstack(df.b))`